# Installing mongodb with homebrew in mac mountain lion ( 10.8.5 ) never ends

Tags: mongodb, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

I'm in 10.8.5 and traying to install mongodb but it just never ends, here is the output:

> ~ r01010010$ brew reinstall mongodb
>   ==> Reinstalling mongodb 
>   ==> Downloading http://downloads.mongodb.org/src/mongodb-src-r2.4.7.tar.gz Already
>   downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mongodb-2.4.7.tar.gz
>   ==> Downloading patches
>
> ################################################################## 100,0%
>
> ==> Patching patching file src/third_party/v8/SConscript
>   ==> scons install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.7 -j4 --64 --cc=/usr/bin/clang --cxx=/usr/bin/clang++

So the las line is the last thing i get and still there like open (maybe an infinite loop).

Comment: Mine is hanging in the same place, any update? How long did you wait before quitting. How long should it take normally?

Comment: It finally finished for me I just had to wait like 40minutes or so

Comment: 40 minutes?, really? i just stopped it before. I just installed mongodb from the scratch. Here is this problem "solved?", https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/23517

Comment: This started happening to me after I upgraded to Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I also got this message:

> Warning: No developer tools installed.
>   You should install the Command Line Tools.
>   Run `xcode-select --install` to install them.

and actually running the following command solved the issue.